# InvalidOperationException: The view 'ViewName' was not found after adding route

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-routing

After setting up pagination for my web app, I decided to change the url so that it looks nicer. Everything worked perfectly until I decided to add a route which gives me the following error after I change page

> "InvalidOperationException: The view 'Books' was not found. The
>   following locations were searched: /Views/Shared/Books.cshtml"

And the routing

```
routes.MapRoute
(
     name: "pagination",
     template: "Books/Page/{page}",
     defaults: new {Controller = "Core", action = "Books"}
);
```

There doesn't seem to be any typo and I've checked thrice that the controllers and views are in the correct path and have the correct methods.
What may be the problem here? Its not searching in the right folder for the view

Comment: Why are all of your routes defaulting to books?

Comment: Do you have a view inside `Views/Core` folder like `~/Views/Core/Books.cshtml`?

Comment: Yes that view exists

Comment: @David make `page` placeholder optional ie `{page?}` You should also update the question to show where this route is added in relation to any other routes if any

Comment: This question is missing a proper [MCVE]. Also, that's not a routing problem, that's a problem in your Controller since the route does not directly returns the View

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you make `page` optional and try again? *If page is null inside Books action method, then you could throw a custom error inside the method.*

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "pagination",
        template: "Books/Page/{page?}"
        defaults: new { controller = "Core", action = "Books"});
});
```

Or use attribute routing.

```
public class CoreController : Controller
{
   [HttpGet("/Books/Page/{page?}")]
   public IActionResult Books(int? page) { ... }
}
```